# The relation between Shannon capacity and Witsenhausen rate of graphs

Tags: it.information-theory

The Witsenhausen rate of a graph $G$ is given by $$R(G)=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\chi(G^{\boxtimes m})^{\frac{1}{m}}$$ where $\boxtimes$ is the [strong product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_product_of_graphs) (refer formula $1$ on page $2$ here http://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.3885.pdf). In the reference they have used logarithm of chromatic number.

It is clear $R(G)\Theta(G)\geq|\mathcal{V}(G)|$ where $\Theta(G)$ is the Shannon Capacity of $G$.

My question is whether $R(G)\Theta(G)=|\mathcal{V}(G)|$ holds true for all $G$?

If so, how to see this? Is there an analog of Lov\'asz theta for this function or is this just $\frac{|\mathcal{V}(G)|}{\vartheta(G)}$?